# Dart, how to unit test a function with mocking method inside

Tags: dart

I want to unit test a function with mocking a function inside.

This is the simplified code I want to test:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

Future<int> function() async {
  final int value = await API(); // This returns a int.

  return value + 1;
}

void main() {
  test('test function, (when api() returns 1)', () {
    expect(function(), completion(equals(2)));
  });
}
```

When testing, I don't want to call the real `API()` function but, want to mock it instead. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The typical way to do this would be to modify `function` to take an optional argument (in this case, of type `Future<int>Function()?`) that it would invoke if supplied, falling back to calling `API()` if `null`.  Alternatively create a class to wrap calls to `API()`, and then you can replace an instance of that class with a `Mock` (basically what `package:file`, `package:platform`, etc. do).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I'll go with the first solution.